# Jquery Ajax pending request slowing down others page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have prepared a dashboard and the below ajax call is working after home page load but the problem is 
until finishing the ajax call, if I click on another page then the page showing loading due to the pending ajax request.

For your kind information, the ajax call takes 25 sec for a large volume of data.

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'https://mysite/service/AjaxPrepareDashBoard',
                    data: "agent_id=25364523",
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'text',
                    async: true,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                      $("#datasource_loader").html('<img src="https://mysite/images/ajax-loader.gif">');
                    },
                    success: function (response)
                    {
                        if (response) {
                            $("#datasource_loader").html('');
                            $("#datasource").prepend(response);
                            $(".print_trx_list").html(response);
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Comment: set `async: true,` as `async: false`

Comment: I did but then the page getting freeze until complete the request

Comment: _“the ajax call takes 25 sec for a large volume of data”_ - and probably uses the PHP session as well? Then all other scripts are blocked from accessing the session, for as long as this request is using it. To avoid that, you have to call `session_write_close` as early as possible in that long-running script.

Answer (score 0):

When user click on another page then you should abort the ongoing ajax request. Adding the dummy code below how abort works.

You need to abort the call when you start redirection to another page.

```js
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: "name=John&location=Boston",
    success: function(msg){
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});

//kill the request
xhr.abort()
```

Comment: I did as you have said but still remaining same

Comment: Can you please update your code with your latest changes? And also the code where you are aborting the ajax call and redirecting ?

Comment: $("#nav a").click(function () {             
                xhr.abort();
                console.log($(this).attr("href"));
                window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
            });

Comment: Yes, you also need to empty the "datasource_loader" div which you are populating in beforeSend of ajax request. You are adding it there but not removing its content when user navigates to another page.


$("#datasource_loader").empty();

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this, so that we can see the issue. It would be very helpful for us to debug.